# How to further troubleshoot a problem with my condensate pump?

Tags: boiler, pump, condensate

During a recent trip to be basement I noticed that the floor was wet under my condensate pump. This pump collects the water from my water heater but it's powered through my boiler.

There was a lot of water in the condensate pump box. I poured a little bit more to trigger the pump and the pump didn't turn on.

I opened the pump, cleaned the water in the box and checked the floaters. The pump is old but everything seemed OK. Then I tested the outlet were the pump was connected, using a lamp I had in the basement (I verified the lamp was working in a different outlet). **The lamp didn't work on this outlet**. The boiler itself is working (heating went off the other day and I can see some of the green lights in the boiler, telling me it's powered)

At this point I don't know how to further troubleshoot my problem. I don't know if I need either a plumber or an electrician to service my boiler (which of the two is better suited for the job?) and tell me why that outlet is not working or if there is anything else I can try with the breaker panel to reset any GFCI outlets (I would hate to call a electrician so they just flip a switch).

I could replace the condensate pump (probably I will), but I think it is safe to assume that it doesn't get powered through the boiler's outlet.  How can I further troubleshoot my issue?

[image: the boiler box]

Comment: Open up the cover on your circuit breaker panel and look for any tripped breakers. The handle should be in the middle position and many (most? all?) should have a window with a little red flag showing on a tripped breaker. Turn the breaker off then on if you find one tripped. If it immediately trips again you've got a different problem. If none are tripped, you've had something go wrong in the wiring - there are plenty of questions here about trouble shooting a dead outlet, or you could call an electrician if you're not up for the task.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I took a look at the breaker and none (including the one labeled as "boiler") seemed tripper (neither blatantly in the middle or off). I'll double check. I guess that I'll need an electrician, because reached this point, I'm completely out of my comfort zone and I don't want to break any expensive machinery or get electrocuted.

Comment: Run an extension cord to the pump and verify it works. If the pump failed it may have overloaded that circuit someplace causing an open circuit like right there at the outlet especially if backstabs were used. I say this as furnace circuits are normally dedicated but the other equipment to the system may be on a different circuit.